# Separate enum declaration and initialization

Tags: c++, enums

I want my header file to look like

```
//Header.h
--Declare enum

//Cpp.cpp
enum class {TEST = 2}
```

Right now I am just doing `enum class {TEST = 2}` in the header file.
Every file I have now has cpp and header file as pair. I don't want this file to be a header file without pair

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074084/forward-declaring-enum-class-not-working

Comment: `I don't want this file to be a header file without pair` How odd desire. Is that an ocd thing (no offence)?

Comment: Thank you :) So the answer is "I can't" ? Haha

Comment: @user2079303 yea its ocd thing! It would be nice if you reason me out of it : )